# cant create view with model cause it dont have key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I just added a model with name `AdminViewModel` 
content in Model:

```
namespace TestNewATM3._0.Models
{
    public class AdminViewModels
    {
        [Key]
        public int keyID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "New Cart userame")]
        public string Admin_AddCartUser { get; set; }

    }
}
```

but when I create a new model with template "Create" its just say that i don't 
have a Key. Can some please explain whats wrong?

I Always do this and never had this problem before.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbPjq.png)

Comment: It is preferred to copy/paste the _text_ of errors into the question. Images cannot be googled.

Comment: Oh oke, sorry i'm kinda new. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Is that `._0.` namespace really in your own code?

Comment: Its view model. It should not be in you `Models` folder - move it to another folder say ViewModels so its not associated with EF. And remove the `[Key]` attribute (that's an EF specific attribute)

Comment: Thanks it works know.